# How to get python to know what directory you're working in

Tags: python, module, directory, chdir, working-directory

I have a program that I wrote that goes through all of the files in a directory and looks for files with a flag and then inputs them into a different program. It works great, the only thing that I am trying to do now it put the script in one location on a box, and then have it know to look in the directory that I am currently in as the working directory. Currently all I do is mv the script into whatever directory I am working in and just call it from there, but that is tedious and requires me to constantly be cp'ing the script.

I am just hoping there is a little more elegant way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what about

```
import os

loc = os.getcwd()
```

Answer (score 1):

The  **__*file*__** object can return such information:

```
import os

os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Comment: This will give you the directory that the current *file* is in which may not be your current directory.

Comment: Right, I misread the original question. Also, as a result, this must be called form __within__ a file to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable passing the working directory as an argument to the script, the following approach will work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os

workingDir = sys.argv[1]
os.chdir (workingDir)

# Your code here
```

Comment: `os.getcwd()` is much better.

Comment: Why? os.getcwd() gets one the present working directory but I fail to understand how that will help run code supposed to run locally in a different sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect use for `os.walk()` the example from the help would be a good starting point:

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
    print root, "consumes",
    print sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files),
    print "bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files"
    if 'CVS' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('CVS')  # don't visit CVS directories
```